# How to use different class object in a new class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I acquired problem called '"*Your class*" is not subscriptable', because itizializing object makes itself an instance of my class object, though i define it in my function "*plot_decision_region*" as an instance of ndarray.

Unable to use ndarray's method due to the fact, that I cant assing ndarray class to the object of my class. I think it's not wise to define new function that will imitate desired function of ndarray, but couldn't find the solution due to my problems with defining it. So I came here looking for help of smart and wise people of these site.
Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
class Perceptron(object):
    def fit(self, X: np.array, Y: np.array, eta: float, iter_ep: int):
        np.random.RandomState(1)
        self.vv = np.random.normal(loc = 0.0, scale = 0.01, size = X.shape[1]+1)
        self.Error_total = []
        for i in range(iter_ep):
            error = 0
            for x, y in zip(X, Y):
                update = eta*(y - self.predict(x))
                self.vv[1:] += update*x
                self.vv[0] += update
                error += int(update != 0.0)
            self.Error_total.append(error)
        return self
    def predict(self, x_examples):
        return np.where(np.dot(x_examples, self.vv[1:])+self.vv[0] >= 0.0, 1, -1)
    def plot_decision_regions(X_ex: np.array, Y_ex: np.array, classifier, resolution = 0.02):
        # initializing markers and color mapping for future usage
        markers = ('', 's', '^', 'o', '4')
        colors = ('red', 'blue', 'green', 'cyan', 'grey')
        cmap = ListedColormap(colors[:len(np.unique(y))])
        # getting the decision surface
        x1_min, x1_max = np.min(X_ex[:, 0])-1, np.max(X_ex[:, 0])+1
        x2_min, x2_max = X_ex[:, 1].min-1, X_ex[:, 1].max+1
        xx1, xx2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x1_min, x1_max, resolution), 
                               np.arange(x2_min, x2_max, resolution))
        Z = classifier.predict(np.array([xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]).T)
        Z = Z.reshape(xx1.shape)
        plt.contourf(xx1, xx2, Z, apha = 0.3, cmap=cmap)
        plt.xlim(xx1.min(), xx1.max())
        plt.ylim(xx2.min(), xx2.max())
        #Printing plot of classes
        for idx, cl in enumerate(np.unique(Y_ex)):
            plt.scatter(X_ex[Y_ex == cl], X_ex[Y_ex == cl], alpha = 0.8, colors = colors[idx], marker = markers[idx], label = np.where(cl == 1, 'verticolor', 'setosa'), edgecolor = 'black')
# Receiving dataset
s = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/curran/a08a1080b88344b0c8a7/raw/0e7a9b0a5d22642a06d3d5b9bcbad9890c8ee534/iris.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(s, header = None, encoding = 'utf-8')
y = np.where(df.iloc[1:101, 4].values == 'setosa', -1, 1)
x = df.iloc[1:101, [0,2]].values
x = x.astype(float)
plt.scatter(x[0:50,0], x[0:50, 1], color = 'blue', marker = 's', label = 'setosa')
plt.scatter(x[50:101, 0], x[50:101, 1], color = 'red', marker = '^', label = 'versicolor')
plt.xlabel('sepal_length, cm')
plt.ylabel('petal_length, cm')
plt.show()
#Learning if the model by dataset
ppn = Perceptron()
ppn.fit(x, y, 0.1, 10)
plt.plot(range(1, len(ppn.Error_total)+1), ppn.Error_total, marker = 'o')
plt.xlabel('Число эпох, ед')
plt.ylabel('Кол-во обновлений, ед')
plt.show()
#Visualizing of the model
ppn.plot_decision_regions(x, y, ppn)
plt.xlabel('sepal_length, cm')
plt.ylabel('petal_length, cm')
plt.legend(loc = 'upper left')
plt.show()
```

Here's a traceback:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Home/.spyder-py3/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Home/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\.spyder-py3\untitled1.py:64 in <module>
    ppn.plot_decision_regions(x, y, ppn)

  File ~\.spyder-py3\untitled1.py:33 in plot_decision_regions
    x1_min, x1_max = np.min(X_ex[:, 0])-1, np.max(X_ex[:, 0])+1
TypeError: 'Perceptron' object is not subscriptable
```

I've tried to assign ndarray class to the object X_ex in a different function x, but no matter what the IDE kept saying (thought I did try to assign this argument):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ~\.spyder-py3\untitled1.py:60 in <module>
    ppn = Perceptron()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x1'
```

As you can see, I did initialize argument X_ex as an instance of ndarray, but nevertheless after assigning ppn to the '*Perceptron*' class every argument of it become an instance of class 'Perceptron'.

Comment: Writing `def plot_decision_regions(X_ex: np.array, ...)` does not change that an instance of the *own* class is passed as implicit first argument when calling a method of the class. You just wrote a type annotation that has no effect in runtime.

Comment: Have you tried simply adding a `self` parameter: `def plot_decision_regions(self, X_ex: np.array, ...)`

Comment: "after assigning ppn to the 'Perceptron' class every argument of it become an instance of class 'Perceptron'"  is incorrect to the point of near-nonsense.   Python isn't typed, those types are just hints / suggestions.  The problems here are simple and not related to subtle type issues:  instance methods must take a `self` first argument, and the arguments in your type constructor call must match those in the corresponding `__init__` (which you've clearly deleted in the listing above).

Comment: @mkrieger1 has nailed the problem.   `plot_decision_regions` should work exactly like `fit`, and that means adding a `self` argument.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, I did try that, but, unfortunately, that brings up another problem :               File ~\.spyder-py3\untitled1.py:34 in plot_decision_regions
    x2_min, x2_max = X_ex[:, 1].min-1, X_ex[:, 1].max+1

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'

Comment: Because `X_ex[:1].min` is a method, not a number. That doesn't mean that the previous change was wrong, just that you have more problems to fix.

Answer (score 0):

mkrieger1 solved this problem: adding a `self` parameter here `def plot_decision_regions(self, X_ex: np.array, ...)` solves the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).